# HTTP call using Observable not working

Tags: angular, observable

In the function below, I have two calls to the server, one using Observable and the other using Promise. The call using Observable does not reach the server but the one using promise does. Any idea why?

```
public placeOrder(order:string) {

//Using Observable
this.http.post(this.newOrderUrl, {order: order}, this.options)
.map((response:Response) => {
  console.log('new order', response.json())
})

//Using Promise
this.http.post(this.newOrderUrl, {order: order}, this.options)
.toPromise()
.then((response:Response) => {
  console.log('new order', response.json())
})
}
```

Comment: You are not returning anything inside the `map`. Return the `response.json()`

Comment: You should subscribe to the observable in order to execute it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the response.json() if you are using Observable

```
 return this.http.post(this.newOrderUrl, {order: order}, this.options)
   .map((response: Response) => response.json()
 );
```

and in your component, call using subscribe()

```
this._myservice.placeOrder('somestring').subscribe((orders: any) => {
});
```

Comment: response.json is only neccesary if you're using the "depreciated" http